# Undefined variable on php script

Tags: php, xml, twitter

I am getting notice on line 30 that twetout is undefined variable

```
    <?php 
    $username = "tomaskutaj";/*
    $limit = 5;
    $feed = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$username.'&count='.$limit;*/
    $feed ="http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=@tomaskutaj";
    $tweets = file_get_contents($feed);

        $tweets = str_replace("&", "&", $tweets);   
        $tweets = str_replace("<", "<", $tweets);
        $tweets = str_replace(">", ">", $tweets);
        $tweet = explode("<item>", $tweets);
    $tcount = count($tweet) - 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $tcount; $i++) {
    $endtweet = explode("</item>", $tweet[$i]);
    $title = explode("<title>", $endtweet[0]);
    $content = explode("</title>", $title[1]);
        $content[0] = str_replace("&#8211;", "&mdash;", $content[0]);

        $content[0] = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $content[0]);
        $content[0] = str_replace("$username: ", "", $content[0]);
        $content[0] = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $content[0]);
        $content[0] = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $content[0]);
    $mytweets[] = $content[0];
}
$x=1;
while (list(, $v) = each($mytweets)) {
    $tweetout .= "<div>$v</div>\n";
    if ($x==1){
    $first=$tweetout;
    };
    $x++;
}
if ((strstr($first,'#tomaskutaj'))&&(strstr($first,'@tomaskutaj')))
echo($first);
  ?>
```

But after I added before last while saying '$tweetout='';' it runs the script but doesnt get any output and no error either, where is the problem?

Comment: Brad is right on the money.  Also, as a matter of course, you might want to consider using *[foreach()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)* instead of *list()* and *each()*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely add a

```
$tweetout = "";
```

before your loop, appending to a non existing string is an error.

The reason you're getting nothing on the screen is that $first does not contain #tomaskutaj, and the if-statement at the end requires that (and @tomaskutaj which is there) to print anything.

Comment: Ah, yes, +1, there are two problems.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to append to a variable that is not defined.

```
$tweetout .= "<div>$v</div>\n";
```

PHP gives you a notice, as in most cases, this happens because you typo-ed a variable name.  You don't get any errors, as PHP just assumes you meant to append to `null` and continues.

To resolve the issue, before your `while` loop, define `$tweetout`:

```
$tweetout = '';
```

Comment: thats whats I tried but now it runs without any errors but no output either

Comment: @TomasSmith, put that **before** your loop, not after it.  Right after `$x=1;`.